# Can we change the custom error element's property "mode" to ON/OFF based on user log in?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Is there any possible way to change the mode property to ON / OFF based on user log in.

Comment: Which user? What if you have 10 concurrent users?

Comment: Admin user has to see the original error. And Other user has to see only default redirect page.

Comment: Then why not redirect non admins to a different page?

Comment: How do we redirect non admins to a different page? I mean how to identify the log in users at custom error element.

Comment: Do it in the default error page. You can't change the `web.config` per user. The web application will restart every time you change the file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change the `web.config` file (which would both restart the web application and effect *all* users), consider redirecting non-admins to a different error page   or admins to a special error page (from within your normal error page).